# easy way to create global (JVM) maximum weight for caches?

Tags: java, guava

I would like to have several Cache objects in my application and I'd like them to share a maximum weight.  So given some total weight X, I'd like the sum of the weights of the cached items across all my caches to not exceed X.  I don't know how many caches will be needed up front, nor do the caches need to be 'fair' -- if one is heavily used while others are not, it should be able to take the lion's share of the global maximum.  I don't want misses on a cache because its considered full while other caches are mostly un-used and that space could be allocated by the heavily used cache.  These will be keeping me from going back to disk to get data, so low miss rates are important.

I thought about having a Weigher implementation that used a static variable that kept the total cached weight.  Then a Weigher would return the weight of the object, if that weight is less than the total remaining space, I'd return the weight as-is.  If it's more than the total weight left, I could return Long.MAX_VALUE so the item is not cached.  Each cache would have a high maximum weight, probably Long.MAX_VALUE-1 so that an element can always be inserted as long as we can calculate/allocate a weight for it.

The problem is that I don't see any way to know the total weight of cached objects.  I could decrement the total weight w/ eviction listeners, but there's no way that I can see to be notified when something gets inserted into the cache, nor do the cache stats reflect this in their data.

Is there any workaround for this or approach I could take to achieve this functionality?  I have a custom cache implementation that handles global weights, but lacks many of the features provided by the Guava cache, so I'd like to avoid re-implementing stuff if possible.  Though I don't mind trying to wire this into the Guava Cache if you can point me in a general direction.

Comment: Your proposed Weigher wouldn't work, as the item with a MAX_VALUE weight would flush the entire cache. (Yes, we could optimize that, but it's not simple, and it's not clear that it's worth it.)

Comment: The closest is Jive's [heap-bounded cache](https://github.com/Omega1/voldemort/blob/master/src/java/voldemort/store/memory/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java). This was a fork from an early version of ConcurrentLinkedHashMap, but before realizing the algorithms in its official release (and now in Guava). It worked for them as an alternative to soft-ref (high GC penalty), but not generally useful/safe enough to be part of Guava's caching library.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the pointer, I will check that out.  @fry, i realized that about MAX_VALUE once I get into the code a little deeper.  Has there been any thought to a ConstrainedCache -- combining it w/ the Constraints stuff that's already there.  That would have let me define the global weight w/in the constraint and might have been an ok solution, for me at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guava caches do not interact with each other at all -- there's no "global" interaction -- but `softValues()` is the traditional way to make "memory-sensitive" caches, since soft references are collected by the GC (typically in globally least-recently-used order), but only when memory is tight.

I don't even believe Guava caches *internally* keep track of their total weight -- they track total weight on a per-segment basis, I believe, but keeping track of the total weight would require too much locking.

Comment: I know they don't interact globally, but I'd like them to =)

softValues did not feel appropriate as I'd like to be able to have items evicted from the cache without GC having to handle it, I'd like to keep GC pressure as low as possible.

I did notice in the code that the segments keep their total weight, I'd take an approximate and not thread safe view of the total weight.  I'd end up with some extra loads here and there, but I'd guess those would be made up for by the time savings from all the times I get a hit and avoid going to disk again.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that with a Guava cache, but if I were you I'd try the softValues implementation first, do some benchmarks, and only then see if I needed to move to another cache implementation.

Comment: I'm looking at the LocalCache code, it seems that Weigher.weight is called to get the weight of the entry which is then inserted in recordWrite.  It does not look like the insert is refused if the weight would put the cache over the limit, instead its inserted and then the oldest entries are removed until the weight is below the maximum, so yeah, using Long.MAX_VALUE as a signal to not insert would not work

Comment: It appears that using softValues is not ideal.  This works in that it avoids the OOM you'd get from not having any maximum size (count or weight) enforced on the cache, but there are pretty high latency spikes as the GC kicks in to clean up the soft values of the cache and avoid the OOM -- this is what I was hoping to avoid with the global limit enforced across caches & hard refs.

Comment: I'd be curious if you can tweak GC configuration settings to address that, but yeah -- I'm not sure this is a doable thing.

Comment: So would your recommendation be to extend LoadingCache and implement for this custom case?  If so, would using LocalCache as the storage be appropriate?  Is there a particular reason its package protected?

Comment: It's package protected because we might rewrite it completely at any time, breaking any code that depends on it.  My recommendation would be to either find some more normal way of doing things -- picking an explicit upper bound for each cache locally would be my first choice, to find some other non-Guava caching system that suits your needs, or to suck it up and write your own cache from scratch.  I don't know if option 2 is feasible, and I'd hate doing option 3, but it may be your only choice given your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I see only one solution: Can you just combine these into a single cache with a composite key of some kind?

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion.  The keys are always Longs, and the values are the same wrapper object, just parameterized based on what kind of stuff is in it.  That'd make the Weigher implementation a bit tricky, instanceof won't work directly since every value will be an instance of the same type, so I'd have to inspect the generic parameter; though I could see about adding a getType() method to the wrapper which will return the Class it's parameterized with.  I think I will take some time to look into this.  Thanks for the suggestion.